# using a class method in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I just start do work on MVC4 Asp.Net

I have this class in my models

```
namespace PhoneBook.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string  Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public static String writeasd(){
        return "asd";}
    }
```

I have this method in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Main()
      {
        ViewBag.Username = Request.Form["username"];
        ViewBag.Password = Request.Form["password"];
          var user = new User() 
        return View(user);
      }
```

However when I tried to call this method from my view like this:

@User.writeasd()

It gives error. What is the problem? Can you help me?

Note : I have @using PhoneBook.Models in the beginning of my view

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: actually not error . Non of my class methods appear when I write User.

Comment: Do you have `@using PhoneBook.Models` in your view?

Answer (score 0):

When using a strongly typed view as you are there, you need two things.

One is a model directive

```
@model PhoneBook.Models.User
```

Then you can reference your model using the Model property of the view page.

So in your instance, you would use

```
@Model.writeasd()
```

HTH